# SageMaker batch transform error Requested instance type cannot work with all containers of the model

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

I'd appreciate your help with this error: botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the CreateTransformJob operation: Requested instance type cannot work with all containers of the model: ml.m5.4xlarge

batch_transformer = pretrained_model.transformer( instance_count=Instance_Count, instance_type=InstanceType, output_path=s3_output_data_path, assemble_with="Line", accept="text/csv", # "application/jsonlines" max_payload=Max_Payload, env = hyper_params_dict,
sagemaker_session=Sagemaker_Session
)

batch_transformer.env = hyper_params_dict

Making the predictions on the input data
batch_transformer.transform( s3_input_data_path, content_type="application/jsonlines", split_type="Line" )

batch_transformer.wait()

Comment: What is the model you are running batch inference with, some models may require GPUs for inference.